# How do I reverse the order of a list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamic list that I am trying to switch the current order on. In this example it is 1,2,3 I am trying to make it 3,2,1

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

If it was not dynamic i would use `$('li:first').before('li:last')` a couple times but the number of elements is always changing, is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: they are styled a certain way and when the website goes responsive they are in the wrong order and I cant fix it with CSS

Comment: How are you adding them dynamically? why not just prepend them instead?

Comment: on page load an ajax function populates the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to give ul an id, but this should work:

```
$('ul').append($('ul').find('li').get().reverse());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv435/)

Comment: for simplicity i kept it as a normal ul, let me test this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DmT5y/1/ did not work

Comment: turns out you have to add the method get() before reverse(); added fiddle

Comment: Use .append, not .html

Comment: @FelixKling why? then I would have to remove the lis with the original order.

Comment: `.html` will create new DOM elements. You don't have to remove the elements beforehand, they are simply moved: *"You can also select an element on the page and insert it into another. [...] If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)"* http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 4):

Another simple solution:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/SxKh6/

---

Or even faster with plain JavaScript:

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = li.length; i-- ;) {
    li[i].parentNode.appendChild(li[i]);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/SxKh6/1/

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes and to be the accepted one imo

Answer (score 3):

Many ways, one of them:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nV6wg/3)

```
$('ul').append(function () {
    return $(this).children().get().reverse()
});
```

**EDIT** using append() will keep bound events to children

Comment: so this works, what does the ('*') mean/target?

Comment: This won't work if the li elements have children as well.

Comment: @FelixKling that's a good point! Better would be to prepend each children instead